# Synchronized thread copy from source to destination

Tags: python, multithreading, tkinter, synchronization

My goal is to copy large amount of files from my file server to USB disk or another disk for some backup. For this mission I want to write a program that uses threads to copy the files, and let the user know what is happening behind the scenes.

This is the program I wrote:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import filedialog
import datetime
import os
import shutil
import threading
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor

count = 0  # Counts copied files
Ex_dirs_list = []  # Excluded directories - those directories won't be copied.
task_counter = 0  # Counter for tracking the number of tasks
counter_lock = threading.Lock()  # Lock for updating the counter safely

def copy_file(srcfile, dstfile):
    # function to copy file from source to destination
    os.makedirs(os.path.dirname(dstfile), exist_ok=True)
    shutil.copy2(srcfile, dstfile)

def copy_files_parallel(srcfile, dstfile):
    global count
    global task_counter

    try:
        copy_file(srcfile, dstfile)
        return True
    except Exception as e:
        StatusText.insert(tk.INSERT, f"Error copying {srcfile} to {dstfile}: {e}")
        StatusText.see("end")
        return False

def copy_directory(src_dir, dst_dir):
    global count
    global task_counter
    excluded_dirs_set = set(os.path.basename(x) for x in Ex_dirs_list)

    dirs = '\n'.join(Ex_dirs_list)
    StatusText.insert(tk.INSERT, f"Coping files from {src_dir} to {dst_dir}.\nIgnores following directories:\n{dirs}\n\n")
    StatusText.see("end")

    start = datetime.datetime.now()
    with ThreadPoolExecutor() as executor:
        futures = []
        for root, dirs, files in os.walk(src_dir):
            base_dir = os.path.basename(root)
            if base_dir in excluded_dirs_set:
                # Skip excluded directories
                StatusText.insert(tk.INSERT, f"Skipping directory: {base_dir}\n")
                StatusText.see("end")
                continue

            dstpath = os.path.join(dst_dir, root[len(src_dir)+1:])
            for file in files:
                srcfile = os.path.join(root, file)
                dstfile = os.path.join(dstpath, file)
                if All_files.get() == 1:  # If all files checked, copy all the files regardless of file changes
                    StatusText.insert(tk.INSERT, f"{srcfile} => {dstfile}: All files\n")
                    StatusText.see("end")
                    futures.append(executor.submit(copy_files_parallel, srcfile, dstfile))
                else:
                    if os.path.exists(dstfile):
                        if os.path.getsize(srcfile) != os.path.getsize(dstfile):
                            StatusText.insert(tk.INSERT, f"{srcfile} => {dstfile}: changed\n")
                            status_text.see("end")
                            futures.append(executor.submit(copy_files_parallel, srcfile, dstfile))
                    else:
                        StatusText.insert(tk.INSERT, f"{srcfile} => {dstfile}: added\n")
                        StatusText.see("end")
                        futures.append(executor.submit(copy_files_parallel, srcfile, dstfile))

    finish = datetime.datetime.now()
    StatusText.insert(tk.INSERT, f"\nSummary:\n=======\nCopied {count} files\nFinished in {(finish - start).total_seconds()} seconds\n\n")
    StatusText.see("end")

def WinBackUp():
    t = threading.Thread(target=copy_directory, args=(FromDir.get(), ToDir.get()))
    t.start()

def ChooseDir(dir):
    global Excluded_dirs

    if dir == "src":
        FromDir.set(filedialog.askdirectory())
    if dir == "dst":
        ToDir.set(filedialog.askdirectory())
    if dir == "exclude":
        directory = filedialog.askdirectory()
        if directory in Ex_dirs_list:
            StatusText.insert(tk.INSERT, f"Error! Can't choose {directory} more than once\n")
        else:
            Ex_dirs_list.append(directory)
            ExcludeText.delete('1.0',"end")
            ExcludeText.insert(tk.END, "\n".join(Ex_dirs_list))
            Excluded_dirs = [os.path.basename(x) for x in Ex_dirs_list]
    if dir == "delete":
        if len(Ex_dirs_list)>=1:
            directory = filedialog.askdirectory()
            if directory in Ex_dirs_list:
                Ex_dirs_list.remove(directory)
                ExcludeText.delete('1.0',"end")
                ExcludeText.insert(tk.END, "\n".join(Ex_dirs_list))
                Excluded_dirs = [os.path.basename(x) for x in Ex_dirs_list]
            else:
                StatusText.insert(tk.INSERT, f"Error! directory {directory} is not in list\n")
        else:
            StatusText.insert(tk.INSERT, f"Error! no directory chosen\n")

win = tk.Tk()
win.geometry("910x350")

ToDir = tk.StringVar()
FromDir = tk.StringVar()
All_files = tk.IntVar()
All_files.set(0)  # Default: copy only the changed files

TilteLabel = tk.Label(win, text="Smart Backup", font=("Arial", 14)).pack()
FromButton = tk.Button(win, text="From", command=lambda:ChooseDir("src")).place(x=10, y=50)
FromEntry = tk.Entry(win, textvariable=FromDir, width=10)
FromEntry.place(x=60, y=50, height=25)

ToButton = tk.Button(win, text="To", command=lambda: ChooseDir("dst")).place(x=150, y=50)
ToEntry = tk.Entry(win, textvariable=ToDir, width=10)
ToEntry.place(x=180, y=50, height=25)

ExcludeButton = tk.Button(win, text="Excluded folders / files", command=lambda: ChooseDir("exclude")).place(x=10, y=90)
ExcludeText = tk.Text(win)
ExcludeText.place(x=10, y=120, height=155, width=250)

DelDirButton = tk.Button(win, text="Del dir", command=lambda: ChooseDir("delete")).place(x=200, y=90)

StatusLabel = tk.Label(win, text="Status")
StatusText = tk.Text(win)
scroll_bar = tk.Scrollbar(win)
scroll_bar.pack(side=tk.RIGHT)
StatusText.place(x=290, y=70, height=205, width=600)
StatusLabel.place(x=290, y=45)

IsAllFiles = tk.Checkbutton(win, text="All files", variable=All_files)
IsAllFiles.place(x=100, y=300)
BackupButton = tk.Button(win, text="Backup", command=WinBackUp).place(x=200, y=300)

win.mainloop()
```

So the program copies the files but the updates is not in real time, for example I see the update in the text widget the file copied but the file is not existing yet in the destination.

As I understand, the OS will manage the threads, so I can't know how many files will be copied at the same time. It's good for me if it is faster than copy one by one (can I check it?)

How can I synchronize the real time updates with the actions happening now, so a file is coping right now will be updated the same time it's happening?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Real-time updates in your file copying application would mean synchronizing the UI updates with the completion of the file copying tasks.

```bash
+---------------------------------------+
| tkinter GUI                           |
| +-------------------+  +------------+ |
| | File Selection    |  | Status Box | |
| +-------------------+  +------------+ |
|                                       |
| [FromDir] --> [copy_directory]        |
|                 |                     |
|                 v                     |
|            [ThreadPoolExecutor]       |
|                 |                     |
|                 v                     |
|          [copy_files_parallel]        |
|                 |                     |
|    [Real-time status updates in GUI]  |
+---------------------------------------+
```

Your current implementation is asynchronous: the file copying operations are submitted to a thread pool, and the UI is updated without waiting for these operations to complete. Hence the discrepancy in the timings between the file copy operation and the UI update.

Instead of inserting text into the status box directly from the `copy_files_parallel` function, use a [callback mechanism](https://pythonexamples.org/python-callback-function/) to update the UI only after the file has been successfully copied.

Since [Tkinter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tkinter.html) is not thread-safe, you should schedule UI updates in the main thread. That can be done using [`tkinter.Tk.after` method](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/after.html), as [illustrated here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74713817/6309).

Change the `update_status` function to be a simple wrapper that schedules the actual UI update using `tk.after`. When the file copy operation is complete, use `tk.after` to schedule the update in the Tkinter main thread.

```py
def copy_files_parallel(srcfile, dstfile):
    try:
        copy_file(srcfile, dstfile)
        win.after(0, update_status, f"Successfully copied {srcfile} to {dstfile}")
        return True
    except Exception as e:
        win.after(0, update_status, f"Error copying {srcfile} to {dstfile}: {e}")
        return False

def update_status(message):
    StatusText.insert(tk.INSERT, message + '\n')
    StatusText.see("end")
```

The `copy_directory` function becomes:

```py
# Other parts of your function 

with ThreadPoolExecutor() as executor:
    futures = []
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(src_dir):
        # Directory and file processing logic 

        for file in files:
            # File handling logic 
            futures.append(executor.submit(copy_files_parallel, srcfile, dstfile))

# Rest of your function
```

Each file copy task submitted to the thread pool will independently schedule its own UI update via `tk.after` when the copy operation is complete. That should makes sure all UI updates occur in the main thread, maintaining thread safety for Tkinter.

Try and copy a mix of large and small files and observe the status updates.
Note: You could also show progress in real-time, like a progress bar or the number of files copied out of the total.

---

As noted by [TheLizzard](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11106801/thelizzard) in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77671623/synchronized-thread-copy-from-source-to-destination/77683921?noredirect=1#comment136955317_77683921):

> In rare cases, even using after `tkinter.after`, you might get errors `(Misc.__del__ is not threadsafe)`.
> It shouldn't happen in this case but in general it's best to use queues to transfer data from the new thread to tkinter

True: using a queue is a good way to keep thread safety when transferring data from worker threads to the Tkinter main thread. You could define a [`queue.Queue`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/queue.html) to transfer messages from worker threads to the Tkinter main thread. `copy_files_parallel` would put messages into the queue instead of directly updating the UI. And a new function would periodically checks the queue and updates the UI with any new messages.

`copy_files_parallel`:

```py
import queue
message_queue = queue.Queue()
# ...
def copy_files_parallel(srcfile, dstfile):
    try:
        copy_file(srcfile, dstfile)
        message_queue.put(f"Successfully copied {srcfile} to {dstfile}")
        return True
    except Exception as e:
        message_queue.put(f"Error copying {srcfile} to {dstfile}: {e}")
        return False
```

New function to process queue messages:

```py
def process_queue():
    while not message_queue.empty():
        message = message_queue.get()
        update_status(message)
    win.after(100, process_queue)  # Poll the queue every 100ms
```

With `update_status` Function:

```py
def update_status(message):
    StatusText.insert(tk.INSERT, message + '\n')
    StatusText.see("end")
```

After initializing your Tkinter window and before calling `mainloop`, add:

```py
process_queue()
win.mainloop()
```

Comment: Note that in rare cases, even using after `tkinter.after`, you might get errors (`Misc.__del__` is not threadsafe). It shouldn't happen in this case but in general it's best to use queues to transfer data from the new thread to `tkinter`.

Comment: @TheLizzard Good point, thank you for the feedback. I have extended the answer with an alternative approach using queue.